# How to sort the dictionary by descending values and ascending key lengths?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I need to get a sorted list of dictionaries in descending order but in ascending order of key length without using modules. Easiest way.

I tried first sorting values then keys, but to no avail.

*python*

```
data = {'Nikita': 1, 'Vectoran': 1, 'Aleksei': 2, 'Maksim': 1,
    'Anton': 1, 'Dmitriy': 1, 'Viktor': 3, 'Sergey': 5,
    'Pavel': 1, 'Roman': 1, 'Artemiy': 1, 'Stepan': 1,
    'Evgeniy': 2, 'Ivan': 1, 'Aleksandr': 2, 'Vadim': 1,
    'Abbas': 1, 'Anna': 1}

newdata = data.items()
res = sorted(newdata, key=lambda k: (k[1],k[0]), reverse=True)
print(res)



*output*

[('Sergei', 5), ('Viktor', 3), ('Evgeniy', 2), ('Aleksei', 2), 
('Aleksandr', 2) .....]

*needed*
               len4         len4         len5          len5           
for example [('Anna', 1), ('Ivan', 1), ('Vadim', 1), ('Roman', 1), 
   len6           len6           len7            len7
('Sergey', 5), ('Viktor', 3), ('Evgeniy', 2), ('Dmitriy', 1)......]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `len` and negate it in the `lambda` function.

This should give you what you want:

```
res = sorted(newdata, key=lambda k: (-len(k[0]), k[1]), reverse=True)

**Output**
[('Anna', 1), ('Ivan', 1), ('Roman', 1), ('Anton', 1), ('Abbas', 1), 
 ('Vadim', 1), ('Pavel', 1), ('Sergey', 5), ('Viktor', 3), ('Nikita', 1), 
 ('Maksim', 1), ('Stepan', 1), ('Aleksei', 2), ('Evgeniy', 2), 
 ('Dmitriy', 1), ('Artemiy', 1), ('Vectoran', 1), ('Aleksandr', 2)]
```

**EDIT: A bit more explanation**

Because you want to sort by length *ascending*, but value *descending*. If both numbers were positive (`(len(k[0]), k[1])`), you would end up sorting on length and then value but both would be ascending OR descending, depending on what you set `reverse` to be. So, in order to sort by length ascending THEN by value descending, we make the length negative with `-len()`, and set `reverse=True`. If you did `(len(k[0]), -k[1])` with `reverse=False` you should get the same result.

Comment: thank you very much! but i have a question, why (-len), how it works

Comment: It's negating the length (making it a negative number) so that you sort one ascending and one descending. I tried to explain a little in my edit.